# I'm trying to combine 3 object lists into one list and display it in a data grid. Only the first list displays though. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm attempting to concatenate 3 lists into one and display it in a WPF data grid. Unfortunately, the first list is the only one that displays. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

```
  public List<object> RetrieveNewAnimalChecklistByAnimalID(int AnimalID)
    {
        List<AnimalVM> checkList = new List<AnimalVM>();
        List<AnimalHandlingNotesVM> checkList2 = new List<AnimalHandlingNotesVM>();
        List<AnimalMedicalVM> checkList3 = new List<AnimalMedicalVM>();


        try
        {

             checkList = RetrieveAnimalByAnimalID(AnimalID);
             checkList2 = RetrieveAnimalHandlingNotesAnimalID(AnimalID);
             checkList3 = RetrieveAnimalMedicalInfoByAnimalID(AnimalID);

            List<object> _checkList = checkList.Cast<object>().ToList();
            List<object> _checkList2 = checkList2.Cast<object>().ToList();
            List<object> _checkList3 = checkList3.Cast<object>().ToList();


            var objectList = _checkList.Concat(_checkList2).Concat(_checkList3).ToList();




            return objectList.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("List not constructed", ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you debugged this to check if there is any data in checkList2  and checkList3, using a break point?

Comment: **Pro Tip** : If you find your self adding numbers after variables, there is a good chance you need to rename them

Comment: There is data in all the lists. I swapped _checkList with _checkList2, and the records for_checkList2 appeared. I did the same for _checkList3. The first thing after 'var objectList =' is the only thing that appears.

Comment: Your pattern works for me, https://dotnetfiddle.net/YD4Ypn, However i have just noticed you are trying to smash 3 different types together in an object list. dont do that, share an interface, and return a list of that interface in your method

Comment: I have also just noticed, your vms share nothing seemingly in common are would seem to be totally unrelated data , what are you trying to do?

Comment: Create a new list of type dynamic or which supports all 3 previous list and Add all the list on that. Currently its overriding the value.

Comment: I'm trying to combine 3 objects lists from different VMs; AnimalVM, MedicalVM, and HandlingNotesVM. They are all related to a checklist for new animals.